# swipe to open left and right panel

Tags: phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm currently getting into [Framework7](https://framework7.io). I found only a few docs, but they didn't help me. My problem is really basic, but I simply cannot figure out my error:

I simply try to open both panels, left and right (not at the same time).

- If I swipe from left to right, the left panel should be opened
- If I swipe from right to left, the right panel should be opened

My HTML part looks like this:

```
<!-- Left panel with reveal effect-->
<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
    <div class="content-block">
        <p>Content left panel</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-right panel-reveal">
    <div class="content-block">
        <p>Content right panel</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7({
    swipePanel: 'both'
});
```

If I change swipePanel to either `left` *or* `right`, the correct one will work as intended... for some reason not both, though.

[According to the docs](https://v1.framework7.io/docs/init-app.html) however, `both` is a valid value for `swipePanel`. There are no JS-errors in my console.

Someone else encountered that problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using framework7 version 3 then

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    swipe: 'both'
});
```

In F3 use swipe instead of swipePanel. swipePanel is for V1